# Does MinGW influence compilation -- a GTK program

Tags: gcc, gtk, mingw

I compiled a GTK program in MinGW environment. It worked perfect. Recently, I updated MinGW and recompiled the GTK program, then the program always stopped with Segmentation fault. I have tried to use gdb to look for errors but I couldn't. The config of GTK is exactly same in the old and new MinGW. Therefore, I am suspicious of MinGW environment that influences compilation. I found the version of gcc is different in two environment:

```
    old MinGW    new MinGW
gcc    3.4.5     4.7.2
```

Any idea? Does anybody meet the situation?

Another clue is about GTK itself. I found the program stopped here:

```
g_signal_emit_by_name(G_OBJECT(g_object_get_data(G_OBJECT(window), "plat_GA_canvas")), "expose-event", G_TYPE_NONE);
```

It is a canvas to draw a image according to different situation. Here it just sends a signal to expose the canvas. The curious thing is that it worked in the old MinGW. So I don't doubt it is the point of the problem. Just maybe a clue. By the way, I compiled the GTK program in a pure Linux environment at home. It also worked perfect.

Any idea? Please help.

@duskast, below is the part of the code. It is a little lengthy.

+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
The problem maybe happened -- `g_signal_emit_by_name`:

```
void ACC_platform_unit_num_changed (GtkWidget *box, GtkWidget *window)
{
  int kind;

  kind = gtk_option_menu_get_history((GtkOptionMenu *)box) + 1;
  if(plat.unit_num != kind)
  {
    plat_GA_canvas_refresh (window);
    g_signal_emit_by_name(G_OBJECT(g_object_get_data(G_OBJECT(window), "plat_GA_canvas")), "expose-event", G_TYPE_NONE);

    plat.unit_num = kind;
    if(plat.unit_num == 1)
    {
      gtk_widget_set_sensitive(g_object_get_data(G_OBJECT(window), "ACC_platform_if_gap"), FALSE);
      gtk_widget_set_sensitive(g_object_get_data(G_OBJECT(window), "ACC_platform_if_big_gap"), FALSE);
      gtk_widget_set_sensitive(g_object_get_data(G_OBJECT(window), "ACC_platform_gap_w"), FALSE);
      gtk_widget_set_sensitive(g_object_get_data(G_OBJECT(window), "ACC_platform_live_load_gap"), FALSE);
    }
    else
    {
      gtk_widget_set_sensitive(g_object_get_data(G_OBJECT(window), "ACC_platform_if_gap"), TRUE);
      if(plat.has_gap)
      {
    gtk_widget_set_sensitive(g_object_get_data(G_OBJECT(window), "ACC_platform_if_big_gap"), TRUE);
    gtk_widget_set_sensitive(g_object_get_data(G_OBJECT(window), "ACC_platform_gap_w"), TRUE);
    gtk_widget_set_sensitive(g_object_get_data(G_OBJECT(window), "ACC_platform_live_load_gap"), TRUE);
      }
      else
      {
    gtk_widget_set_sensitive(g_object_get_data(G_OBJECT(window), "ACC_platform_if_big_gap"), FALSE);
    gtk_widget_set_sensitive(g_object_get_data(G_OBJECT(window), "ACC_platform_gap_w"), FALSE);
    gtk_widget_set_sensitive(g_object_get_data(G_OBJECT(window), "ACC_platform_live_load_gap"), FALSE);
      }
    }
    gap_span_show (g_object_get_data(G_OBJECT(window), "ACC_platform_gap_span_store"));
  }
}
```

The core drawing function:

```
void ACC_GA_draw (cairo_t *cr, int width, int height)
{
/* #define X_MARGIN 30
#define Y_MARGIN 30 */
#define COLUMN_RADIUS_ASSUME 1.6
#define COLUMN_SQUARE_LEN_ASSUME 2.0
  double x, y, x1, y1, x2, y2, scale, x_base, y_base, X_MARGIN, Y_MARGIN;
  double x3, y3, downward_height = 0, downward_width = 0;
  double x_one_unit, y_one_unit, x_total, y_total, gap_value;
  double alpha = 60.0, arrow_side_length = 20.0, arrow_tail_length = 10.0;
  ACC_AXIS *x_axis, *y_axis;
  int i, j, unit_num, downward;
  char *AX, *AY, *Wx_left, *Wx_right, *Wy_top, *Wy_bottom, *gap, *axis;
  cairo_text_extents_t te;

  AX = g_strdup_printf("%.0f", plat.fan_section_AX * 1000);
  AY = g_strdup_printf("%.0f", plat.fan_section_AY * 1000);
  Wx_left = g_strdup_printf("%.0f", plat.walkway_Wx_left * 1000);
  Wx_right = g_strdup_printf("%.0f", plat.walkway_Wx_right * 1000);
  Wy_bottom = g_strdup_printf("%.0f", plat.walkway_Wy_bottom * 1000);
  Wy_top = g_strdup_printf("%.0f", plat.walkway_Wy_top * 1000);

  x_one_unit = plat.fan_section_AX * plat.SDD_num;
  x_total = x_one_unit * plat.unit_num + plat.gap_total + plat.walkway_Wx_left + plat.walkway_Wx_right;
  y_one_unit = plat.fan_section_AY * plat.row_num;
  y_total = y_one_unit + plat.walkway_Wy_bottom + plat.walkway_Wy_top;

  scale = calcu_scale (width, height, x_total, y_total, Wx_left, Wy_top, cr, &X_MARGIN, &Y_MARGIN);

  cairo_set_line_width (cr, NORMAL_LINE_WIDTH * 0.7);
  for(unit_num = 1; unit_num <= plat.unit_num; unit_num++)
  {
    if(unit_num == 1)
      x_base = X_MARGIN;
    else
    {
      double total_gap = 0;

      for(i = 0; i < unit_num - 1; i++)
    total_gap += strtod(g_list_nth(plat.gap_w, i)->data, NULL);

      x_base = X_MARGIN + (x_one_unit * (unit_num - 1) + total_gap) * scale;
    }
    y_base = Y_MARGIN;

    for(i = 0, x_axis = plat.X_axis; x_axis; x_axis = x_axis->next, i++)
    {
      if(i == 0)
    x = x_base;
      else
    x += plat.fan_section_AX * scale;
      y = y_base;
      cairo_move_to(cr, x, y);
      y += y_one_unit * scale;
      cairo_line_to(cr, x, y); /* vertical grid */
      cairo_stroke(cr);

      /* SDD */
      if(i != plat.SDD_num)
      {
    cairo_arrow (cr, x + plat.fan_section_AX / 2 * scale, y + plat.walkway_Wy_bottom * scale, alpha, arrow_side_length, 1, arrow_tail_length);
    cairo_save(cr);
    cairo_set_line_width (cr, BOLD_LINE_WIDTH);
    cairo_set_line_cap(cr, CAIRO_LINE_CAP_SQUARE);
    cairo_move_to(cr, x_base + plat.fan_section_AX / 2 * scale, y + plat.walkway_Wy_bottom * scale + arrow_side_length + arrow_tail_length);
    cairo_rel_line_to(cr, (x_one_unit - plat.fan_section_AX) * scale, 0);
    cairo_stroke(cr);
    cairo_restore(cr);
      }

      /* dim line for A1, A2 ... */
      cairo_move_to(cr, x, y + plat.walkway_Wy_bottom * scale + arrow_side_length + arrow_tail_length + 10);
      cairo_rel_line_to(cr, 0, 20);
      cairo_get_current_point(cr, &x3, &y3);
      if(i != plat.SDD_num)
      {
    cairo_text_align_horizontal_center (cr, AX, 0, 1, plat.fan_section_AX / 2 * scale, -10);
      }
      else
      {
    if(plat.unit_num > 1 && plat.has_gap && unit_num != plat.unit_num)
    {
      gap_value = strtod(g_list_nth(plat.gap_w, unit_num - 1)->data, NULL);
      gap = g_strdup_printf("%.0f", 1000 * gap_value);
      cairo_text_extents(cr, gap, &te);
      if(gap_value * scale < te.x_bearing + te.width)
      {
        downward = 1;
        downward_height = 11;
        downward_width = gap_value * scale;
        cairo_rel_move_to(cr, gap_value / 2 * scale - (te.x_bearing + te.width / 2), 10);
      }
      else
      {
        downward = 0;
        cairo_rel_move_to(cr, gap_value / 2 * scale - (te.x_bearing + te.width / 2), -10);
      }
      cairo_show_text(cr, gap);
      g_free(gap);
    }
    else
      downward = 0;
      }
      if(unit_num == 1 && i == 0)
      {
    cairo_move_to(cr, x - plat.walkway_Wx_left * scale, y + plat.walkway_Wy_bottom * scale + arrow_side_length + arrow_tail_length + 10);
    cairo_rel_line_to(cr, 0, 20);
    cairo_rel_move_to(cr, -25, -10);
    cairo_show_text(cr, Wx_left);
      }
      if(unit_num == plat.unit_num && i == plat.SDD_num)
      {
    cairo_move_to(cr, x + plat.walkway_Wx_right * scale, y + plat.walkway_Wy_bottom * scale + arrow_side_length + arrow_tail_length + 10);
    cairo_rel_line_to(cr, 0, 20);
    cairo_rel_move_to(cr, 3, -10);
    cairo_show_text(cr, Wx_right);
      }

      if(plat.axis_style_SDD == 0) /* 递增 */
    axis = g_strdup_printf("A%d", plat.start_axis_SDD + (unit_num - 1) * (plat.SDD_num + 1) + i);
      else
    axis = g_strdup_printf("A%d", plat.start_axis_SDD + (unit_num - 1) * (plat.SDD_num + 1) - i);
      cairo_text_extents(cr, axis, &te);
      if(!downward || ((i != plat.SDD_num) && (unit_num != 1 && i != 0)))
    cairo_move_to(cr, x3 - te.width / 2, y3 + te.height + 2);
      else
      {
    if(te.width < downward_width)
      cairo_move_to(cr, x3 - te.width / 2, y3 + te.height + downward_height);
    else
    {
      if(i == plat.SDD_num)
        cairo_move_to(cr, x3 - te.width, y3 + te.height + downward_height);
      else
        cairo_move_to(cr, x3, y3 + te.height + downward_height);
    }
      }
      cairo_show_text(cr, axis);
      g_free(axis);
      cairo_stroke(cr);

      for(j = 0, y_axis = plat.Y_axis; y_axis; y_axis = y_axis->next, j++)
      {
    x1 = x_base;
    if(j == 0)
      y1 = y_base + y_one_unit * scale;
    else
      y1 -= plat.fan_section_AY * scale;
    if(i == 0)
    {
      cairo_move_to(cr, x1, y1);
      x1 += x_one_unit * scale;
      cairo_line_to(cr, x1, y1); /* horizontal grid */
      cairo_stroke(cr);
    }

    if(i != plat.SDD_num && j != plat.row_num) /* fan ring */
    {
      cairo_arc(cr, x + plat.fan_section_AX / 2 * scale, y1 - plat.fan_section_AY / 2 * scale, plat.fan_ring_opening_D / 2 * scale, 0, 2 * PI);
      cairo_stroke(cr);
    }

    /* columns */
    if(plat.col_type == 0) /* 砼悬臂住 */
    {
      if(plat.SDD_num % 2 == 0)
      {
        if((i + 1) % 2 == plat.SDD_col_first && (j + 1) % 2 == plat.row_col_first)
        {
          cairo_arc(cr, x, y1, COLUMN_RADIUS_ASSUME * scale, 0, 2 * PI);
          cairo_fill(cr);
          cairo_stroke(cr);
        }
      }
      else
      {
        if(!plat.if_unit_symmetry || unit_num % 2 == 1)
        {
          if((i + 1) % 2 == plat.SDD_col_first && (j + 1) % 2 == plat.row_col_first)
          {
        cairo_arc(cr, x, y1, COLUMN_RADIUS_ASSUME * scale, 0, 2 * PI);
        cairo_fill(cr);
        cairo_stroke(cr);
          }
        }
        else
        {
          if((i) % 2 == plat.SDD_col_first && (j + 1) % 2 == plat.row_col_first)
          {
        cairo_arc(cr, x, y1, COLUMN_RADIUS_ASSUME * scale, 0, 2 * PI);
        cairo_fill(cr);
        cairo_stroke(cr);
          }
        }
      }
    }
    else if(plat.col_type == 1) /* 钢柱 */
    {
      cairo_save(cr);
      cairo_set_line_width (cr, 2 * NORMAL_LINE_WIDTH);
      cairo_move_to(cr, x, y1 - COLUMN_SQUARE_LEN_ASSUME / 2 * scale);
      cairo_rel_line_to(cr, 0, COLUMN_SQUARE_LEN_ASSUME * scale);
      cairo_move_to(cr, x - COLUMN_SQUARE_LEN_ASSUME / 2 * scale, y1 - COLUMN_SQUARE_LEN_ASSUME / 2 * scale);
      cairo_rel_line_to(cr, COLUMN_SQUARE_LEN_ASSUME * scale, 0);
      cairo_move_to(cr, x - COLUMN_SQUARE_LEN_ASSUME / 2 * scale, y1 + COLUMN_SQUARE_LEN_ASSUME / 2 * scale);
      cairo_rel_line_to(cr, COLUMN_SQUARE_LEN_ASSUME * scale, 0);
      cairo_stroke(cr);
      cairo_restore(cr);
    }
    else if(plat.col_type == 2) /* 砼框架柱 */
    {
      cairo_rectangle(cr, x - COLUMN_SQUARE_LEN_ASSUME / 2 * scale, y1 - COLUMN_SQUARE_LEN_ASSUME / 2 * scale, COLUMN_SQUARE_LEN_ASSUME * scale, COLUMN_SQUARE_LEN_ASSUME * scale);
      cairo_fill(cr);
      cairo_stroke(cr);
    }

    /* dim line of AA, AB ... */
    if(unit_num == plat.unit_num && i == 0)
    {
      cairo_move_to(cr, x1 + plat.walkway_Wx_right * scale + 10, y1);
      cairo_rel_line_to(cr, 20, 0);

      if(j != plat.row_num)
      {
        cairo_text_align_horizontal_center (cr, AY, 1, 1, -10, -plat.fan_section_AY / 2 * scale);
      }

      if(j == 0)
      {
        x2 = x1 + plat.walkway_Wx_right * scale + 10 + 20 - 5;
        y2 = y1 + plat.walkway_Wy_bottom * scale;

        cairo_move_to(cr, x1 + plat.walkway_Wx_right * scale + 10, y1);
        cairo_rel_move_to(cr, 0, plat.walkway_Wy_bottom * scale);
        cairo_rel_line_to(cr, 20, 0);

        cairo_rel_move_to(cr, -10, 25);
        cairo_save(cr);
        cairo_rotate(cr, - PI / 2.0);
        cairo_show_text(cr, Wy_bottom);
        cairo_restore(cr);
      }

      if(j == plat.row_num)
      {
        cairo_move_to(cr, x1 + plat.walkway_Wx_right * scale + 10, y1);
        cairo_rel_move_to(cr, 0, -plat.walkway_Wy_top * scale);
        cairo_rel_line_to(cr, 20, 0);

        cairo_rel_move_to(cr, -10, -1);
        cairo_save(cr);
        cairo_rotate(cr, - PI / 2.0);
        cairo_show_text(cr, Wy_top);
        cairo_restore(cr);
      }
      cairo_stroke(cr);
    }
    else if(unit_num == 1 && i == 0)
    {
      if(plat.axis_style_row == 0) /* 递增 */
        axis = g_strdup_printf("A%c", plat.start_axis_row + j);
      else
        axis = g_strdup_printf("A%c", plat.start_axis_row - j);
      cairo_text_extents(cr, axis, &te);
      cairo_move_to(cr, x_base - plat.walkway_Wx_left * scale - 20, y1 + te.height / 2);
      cairo_show_text(cr, axis);
      g_free(axis);
      cairo_stroke(cr);
    }
      }
    }
  }

  /* walkway line */
  x = X_MARGIN - plat.walkway_Wx_left * scale;
  y = Y_MARGIN - plat.walkway_Wy_top * scale;
  cairo_move_to(cr, x, y);
  cairo_rel_line_to(cr, x_total * scale, 0);
  cairo_rel_line_to(cr, 0, y_total * scale);
  cairo_rel_line_to(cr, -x_total * scale, 0);
  cairo_rel_line_to(cr, 0, -y_total * scale);
  cairo_stroke(cr);

  /* dim total line for A1, A2 ... */
  cairo_move_to(cr, X_MARGIN - plat.walkway_Wx_left * scale, Y_MARGIN + (y_one_unit + plat.walkway_Wy_bottom) * scale + arrow_side_length + arrow_tail_length + 10 + 20 - 5);
  cairo_rel_line_to(cr, x_total * scale, 0);
  cairo_stroke(cr);

  /* dim total line for AA, AB ... */
  cairo_move_to(cr, x2, y2);
  cairo_rel_line_to(cr, 0, -y_total * scale);
  cairo_stroke(cr);

  g_free(AX);
  g_free(AY);
  g_free(Wx_left);
  g_free(Wx_right);
  g_free(Wy_bottom);
  g_free(Wy_top);
}
```

The `expose-event` signal:

```
static gboolean ACC_GA_expose (GtkWidget *canvas, GdkEventExpose *event, gpointer user_data)
{
  cairo_t *cr;

  cr = gdk_cairo_create (canvas->window);
  if(plat.if_GA_draw)
  {
    ACC_GA_draw (cr, canvas->allocation.width, canvas->allocation.height);
  }
  else
  {
    char *local = char_to_utf8 ("Press button \"生成GA\" to update!!");

    cairo_select_font_face(cr, "Sans", CAIRO_FONT_SLANT_NORMAL, CAIRO_FONT_WEIGHT_BOLD);
    cairo_set_font_size(cr, 0.35);
    cairo_move_to(cr, 200, 200);
    cairo_show_text(cr, local);
    g_free(local);

  }
  cairo_destroy (cr);

  return FALSE;
}
```

In main() function:

```
  .
  .
  .
  canvas = gtk_drawing_area_new();
  g_object_set_data(G_OBJECT(window), "plat_GA_canvas", canvas);
  plat.if_GA_draw = 0;
  gtk_widget_show(canvas);
  gtk_box_pack_start(GTK_BOX(sub_main_box), canvas, TRUE, TRUE, 0);
  g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(canvas), "expose-event", G_CALLBACK(ACC_GA_expose), window);
  .
  .
  .
```

+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

Comment: I suppose it's a bug in your original code, the update of MinGW exposed it, since Segment Fault may be stochastic. Could you post your code?

Comment: To duskast: I edited the original post. The codes were added. Please help to check. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GCC 3.4.5 and GCC 4.7.2 are ABI incompatible. You need to rebuild all your code.

Comment: What does `ABI` mean? What do you mean "rebuild"? I have already recompiled my code in GCC 4.7.2. As to GTK, it comes from the third-party.

Comment: I just googled ABI. You are right. Due to ABI issue, GCC 4.7.0 and later is not suggested for MinGw.

Comment: @warem there is nothing wrong with GCC 4.7 and MinGW. You just need to make sure to recompile code that crashes where it didn't before (at least that's how I rule out the compiler ABI in these things `;-)`)

Comment: I did recompile the whole codes. But it crashed while it didn't before. I mean the codes worked in the old MinGw -- gcc 3.4.5 and also worked in a pure Linux environment -- gcc 4.2.1. So the reason for crash can only point to the gcc 4.7.2. After googling, someone said it's prudent to tell people to stay away of the new version, as I completely agree.

Comment: You said that you didn't recompile GTK, which is where you think it is crashing. I understand that recompiling GTK is no fun at all, but it's not really GCC's fault you are trying to use incompatible binary code. It is surely not a reason to tell people to keep using a stone-age compiler version that has a lot more bugs than you should be able to put up with.

Comment: I agreed with your words. Incompatible binary code might come from GTK. My words on gcc are too radical:)

Answer (score 0):

I found a bug in my program. The bug is that `expose-event` for a canvas is exposed more than once and it crashed for the second time. But I don't know why the bug didn't come up in gcc3.4.5 or in a pure Linux environment. After I revised my program, it worked for mingw-gcc4.7.2, mingw-gcc3.4.5 and a pure Linux environment.

On the other hand, gcc4.7.2 works for pre-compiled gtk2.10.11 but fails for pre-compiled gtk2.24.10 in my situation. This is maybe due to ABI issue.

I have posted 2 other posts: [gtk window moved then crash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15675751/gtk-window-moved-then-crash) and [compile GTK+ in MinGW, but failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15588225/compile-gtk-in-mingw-but-failed). They are more or less related with this post.